# Vue not rendering fetched html

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using vue in shopify and am working on a collection page. When I click on a filter, it‘s an href and it updates the url and reloads the page.

So I have a product grid

```js
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <template v-for="(product, index) in collection.products">
    <div class="product-item"></div>
  </template>
</div>
```

And my idea was to just use the same url with fetch so the page doesn‘t reload.

I did this

```js
fetch('/collections?variant=black')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(html => new DOMParser().parseFromText(html, 'text, html'))
  .then(data => {
    document.querySelector('.grid-wrapper').innerHTML = data.querySelector('.grid-wrapper').innerHTML
  })
```

This does not work because I get back the actual `<template v-for…>` as the new innerHTML and vue isnt taking over. How can I solve this

In shopify I converted the object like so

```js
const collection = (() => {
  const collection = {{ collection | json }}
  const products = {{ collection.products | json }}
  collection.products = products
  return collection
})();
```

Then in my vue instance

```js
new Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    collection: collection
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

Comment: Why this traditional DOM manipulation logic ? In Vue, you can directly bind the data by assigning the API response in `collection` object.

Comment: @Rohìt Jíndal I had to convert shopify‘s liquid object to a js object and that is saved in vue data(). The collection object in vue data is just an object, and the response is html so I‘m a bit confused how that would work because I have to loop through that collection object. I do see what you mean though, maybe I have to rethink how I am implementing this

Comment: In `data`, You have to initialize an empty array like this `collection: []` and in mounted() lifecycle hook. You can assign the converted js object into collection like this : `mounted() { this.collection = collection; }`. Also one more observation. data object properties should be inside return. `data() { return {  collection: [] } }`

Answer (score 0):

You're approaching this in the traditional JavaScript way of manipulating the DOM directly. In Vue, we set state which can then be rendered by your template.

Instead:

1. Create a `data` attribute to store your state
2. Under `methods`, write a function to fetch your data, then update the components `data`
3. Call your function in the components `created` hook
4. In you're `template` render the results

   - Don't forget to check it's present first, with `v-if`
   - You can use `v-for` to iterate over, and render lists

Here's a [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-kilby-hupvj5?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

---

I don't have access to your API endpoint, so for demo purposes, am just using the GitHub API, to fetch and render a list of all repos in the Vue.js organization.

Here's what it looks like:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
    Vue.config.productionTip = false;
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      name: 'dbzx10299-demo',
  data() {
    return {
      loaded: false,
      response: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      const demoEndpoint = 'https://api.github.com/orgs/vuejs/repos';
      fetch(demoEndpoint)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.response = data;
        this.loaded = true;
      })
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchData();
  },
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<div class="hello">
  <h2>Vue Repo List - Data fetching example</h2>
  <div v-if="!loaded">Loading...</div>
  <ul v-else>
    <li v-for="(repo, index) in response" :key="index">
      <a :href="repo.html_url" :title="repo.description" target="_blank">
        {{ repo.name }}
      </a>
      <i>★ {{ repo.stargazers_count }}</i>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey I see what you are doing, I just updated my original post. The thing throwing me off is shopify is server side rendered and I need to convert the liquid object to a js object and I was storing that in vue data. The reason for this is I had to then extend the liquid object so I don‘t actually have an endpoint.

Comment: You can do that within your fetch results. The main thing is to not update the DOM directly, but instead reference the `data`. I've updated my answer to (hopefully) make it a little clearer, but if you've got an endpoint I can use, then I can provide you with a real live example.

Comment: Remove `data() {  collection: collection }`, set it to `data() {  collection: null }`, since your data won't have been returned when the component first renders. Then inside your `.then` block, set `this.collection = processedData`.

Comment: Alright my answer is updated, I understand your example but I have no endpoint. The collection stored in vue data is an object and when a filter is applied it adds a query parameter to the url.